# Adding Tag/Label on Structure view on Datagrip

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

[image: Structure view on Datagrip]

I would like to add the tag/label on the each queries that I have. I use similarly created query. I added suggestion in Datagrip suggestion box. I would like to find if there is a such feature(plugin) that I am not aware of.
If I could add tags or label to see on the structure view. I will avoid recreating similar queries.
For example

```
/**
** @PICKING @Tag:Picking 
** Pick slip numbers form sales order table
**/
Select pick_slip_number from sales_order_table

/**
** @Packing @Tag:Paking
**
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just contacted by Jetbrains and I found the solution.

[Code Folding Elements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/folding-code-elements.html?keymap=primary_default)

I created code folding starting with double dash since I am using SQL in Datagrip

```
--region [description] 
/*** 
*** some comment
**/
Select order_number from Sales_Order_Table
--endregion
```

There are other ways to create a Folding Code Elements. The key is to use the one way on the file.
Once you have chosen the style for a file, don't use the other style in that file.
[image: Example of Code Folding Element]

I created as below for the above example

```
--region PrePick
... some code goes here
--endregion

--region Picking Label
... another code goes here
--endregion
```

I had to close the file and reopen to see the change.